# How to replace special HTML element with another in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of texts are as follows (for example):

```
C# is <pre>a great</pre> language <pre class="precontent">of dot net</pre>
```

I want change them in mysql like this :

```
C# is <span>a great</span> language <pre class="precontent">of dot net</pre>
```

This means that the pre tag has class not changed 
how do i it?

Comment: Trying to do this entirely in MySQL is a bad idea. You need to use a parser.

Comment: can you more explain? because i am begginer.

Comment: I mean that this is hard to do in pure SQL and likely to go awry. You are better off reading the data into the programming language of your choice, manipulating it there using an HTML parser, then writing it back to the database.

Comment: tank you. if i want do it in XML file. how do i it?

Comment: I just told you. Beyond that point, you would need to pick a language, try something, and ask a question when you get stuck. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).